# Element just appears when manually click on page selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

My other question has closed as duplicated, but this web scraping already works to change aliexpress countries and currencies, but only if I click on the page manually before the pop-up appears and I can't understand why this is happening.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from os import getcwd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
    "translate_whitelists": {"es": "en"},
    "translate": {"enabled": "true"},
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
}
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--lang=en")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=f"{getcwd()}\chromedriver.exe", options=option)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle)
url = input("Type a aliexpress url: ")
driver.get(url)


# close aliexpress coupon pop-up
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src, '__poplayer')]")))
time.sleep(5)
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src, 'http')]"):
    i.click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()


# change country to india and currençy to usd
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'switcher-info')]/span[@class='ship-to']/i").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("switcher-common").find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[0].click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='address-select-item']//span[@class='shipping-text' and text()='India']"))).click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("switcher-common").find_elements_by_class_name("switcher-currency-c")[1].click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='search-container']//input[@class='search-currency']")[1].send_keys("usd")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-currency='USD']").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("switcher-common").find_elements_by_tag_name("button")[0].click()
```

when I don't click, it return this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I already try to click in a random place like the navbar at the top, but it return a error saying that the pop-up have obscured it. So, as the pop-up appears inside the body, I tried to click on it with:  `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body")`, but nothing changes and finally click with x and y coordinates with: `action.move_by_offset(10,10).click().perform()` and again, nothing happen.

Comment: examine the scripts used on the site.  They may be triggering something based on event handlers attached to the body.  If so try sending a click event to the body... "//body".   Depends on what event handlers are at play there...  could also be a focus change or something like that.  Also consider the possibility that the exception is happening during your "for i in driver.find_elements" loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the cookie with the right values ? as that seems to be the place country and currency are being stored ?

Comment: I haven't tried it that way yet, I don't know how to change cookies, I'll take a look to see if it works, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: also i have loaded the page source in with:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

with open("output1.txt", "w",encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(soup_level1))

And then you see that switcher-info is not to be found, so they have cleverly hidden it.